# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined ArcGIS javascript API

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geojson

Below is my code.I'm tryng to display a GeoJSON layer from ArcGIS online. I get the error,
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>  
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=9">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>ArcGIS GeoJSON Layer</title>  
    <!-- ArcGIS API for JavaScript CSS-->

    <style>
    html, body, #mapDiv {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/esri/css/esri.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://esri.github.io/bootstrap-map-js/src/css/bootstrapmap.css">
     <script src="./vendor/terraformer/terraformer.min.js" </script>
      <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.9/"></script>
     <script src="./vendor/terraformer-arcgis-parser/terraformer-arcgis-parser.min.js" </script>

    <script src="./src/geojsonlayer.js"</script>  

    <script>
    require([
            "esri/map",
            "./src/geojsonlayer",
            "dojo/on",
            "dojo/dom",
            "dojo/domReady!"],
          function (Map, GeoJsonLayer, on, dom) {

            // Create map
            var map = new Map("mapDiv", {
                basemap: "gray",
                center: [-122.5, 45.5],
                zoom: 5
            });

            map.on("load", function () {
                addGeoJsonLayer(url);
            });

            // Add the layer
            function addGeoJsonLayer(url) {
                // Create the laye
                var geoJsonLayer = new GeoJSONLayer({
                    url: "http://services6.arcgis.com/ZHUwet99mNBqTsuu/ArcGIS/rest/services/ABHI/FeatureServer/0/query?where=city%3D%27BENGALURU%27+&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&resultType=none&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Meter&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&multipatchOption=&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&returnDistinctValues=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&quantizationParameters=&sqlFormat=none&f=pgeojson&token="

                });
                // Zoom to layer
                geoJsonLayer.on("update-end", function (e) {
                    map.setExtent(e.target.extent.expand(1.2));
                });
                // Add to map
                map.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
            }
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mapDiv"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are missing a closing angled bracket when calling the terraformer.min.js script.

Problem Line

```
<script src="./vendor/terraformer-arcgis-parser/terraformer-arcgis-parser.min.js" </script>
```

Corrected as

```
<script src="./vendor/terraformer-arcgis-parser/terraformer-arcgis-parser.min.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7,IE=9">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        <title>ArcGIS GeoJSON Layer</title>
        <!-- ArcGIS API for JavaScript CSS-->
      <script>
        dojoConfig = {
            parseOnLoad: false,
            packages: [{
                "name": "src",
                "location": "/src"
            }]
        };
      </script>

        <style>
            html, body, #mapDiv {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/esri/css/esri.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://esri.github.io/bootstrap-map-js/src/css/bootstrapmap.css">
        <script src="./vendor/terraformer/terraformer.min.js" ></script>
        <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.9/"></script>
        <script src="./vendor/terraformer-arcgis-parser/terraformer-arcgis-parser.min.js"> </script>


        <script>
            require([
                        "esri/map",
                        "src/geojsonlayer",
                        "dojo/on",
                        "dojo/dom",
                        "dojo/domReady!"],
                    function (Map, GeoJsonLayer, on, dom) {

                        // Create map
                        var map = new Map("mapDiv", {
                            basemap: "gray",
                            center: [-122.5, 45.5],
                            zoom: 5
                        });

                        map.on("load", function () {
                            addGeoJsonLayer("{geojson url}");
                        });

                        // Add the layer
                        function addGeoJsonLayer(url) {
                            // Create the laye
                            var geoJsonLayer = new GeoJsonLayer({
                                url: url
                            });
                            // Zoom to layer
                            geoJsonLayer.on("update-end", function (e) {
                                map.setExtent(e.target.extent.expand(1.2));
                            });
                            // Add to map
                            map.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
                        }
                    });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="mapDiv"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggested answer. I will try it. Can you tell me what is name and location src in dojo config?

Comment: for example geojsonlayer.js path is /example/geojsonlayer.js in project. dojoconfig is : name: 'asd' and location :'/example' and require use this : 'asd/geojsonlayer'

Comment: okay and is 'asd' a random name?

Comment: yes it is random name.